# Where to find the location of IIS manager connection strings

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis

I was getting an error saying that one of my connection string in my application's web.config file was already defined.

I checked in the IIS settings and when I checked the connection string property it was there already with Entry Type : Inherited.

So I went up the chain and went all the way up to the root of the localhost and checked the connection strings there.

I found a bunch of connection strings there as well.. but they're also all with Entry Type Inherited..

I checked the web.config file inside the wwwroot folder but didn't find any connection strings defined in there..

Where could these connection strings be coming from?...

[image]

Comment: Did you check the machine.config file? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2325473/where-is-machine-config

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Configuration files in .NET are inherited in the following order:

- `systemroot\Microsoft .NET\Framework\versionNumber\CONFIG\Machine.config`
- `systemroot\Microsoft .NET\Framework\versionNumber\CONFIG\Web.config` (ASP.NET only)
- `(application directory)\Web.config`

So the connection strings that show up as "inherited" are specified in either of the upper two files.

Reference: [MSDN: ASP.NET Configuration File Hierarchy and Inheritance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178685.aspx)

If you don't want to alter the machine-wide configuration, you can `<clear />` them from being inherited in your application's configuration as explained in [What does <clear /> signify when specifying a connectionstring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24158072/what-does-clear-signify-when-specifying-a-connectionstring):

```
<connectionStrings>
   <clear />
   <add name="LocalSqlServer" connectionString="..." /> 
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Thank you. I was able to find them inside C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config