# My app doesn't use SQL Server Express but it is looking for a database in App_Data -- why?

Tags: c#, sql-server, iis, reporting-services, sql-server-express

My application uses SSRS (on SQL Server 2017 on a server) and IIS. It runs fine in my IDE (VS 2017 or VS 2015) but when I put it on the server I get an error page.

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

No connection string to SQL Server Express.

Comment: Probably it is the issue discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24158072/what-does-clear-signify-when-specifying-a-connectionstring

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but "connectionString" is not found anywhere in the solution.

Comment: This application hasn't ever before required aspnetdb but it is when I am publishing it to the IIS now. I'm trying to figure out why and remove any reference / namespace that requires that.

Answer (score 0):

- Firstly make sure that your SQL server is running and SQL Server
  browser service is running.

  - Make sure SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.
  - Examine the SQL Server error log for messages confirming that SQL is
    listening on the expected network interfaces and ports.
  - Test server connectivity with PING from the client machine.
  - Test port connectivity using TELNET or PowerShell to the server and
    port from the client machine.
    For example
    a. TELNET  1433
    b. PowerShell: 1433 | % { echo ((new-object Net.Sockets.TcpClient).Connect("YourServerName",$*)) "server listening on TCP port $*" }
  - Check firewall settings.
  - Also check your web.config file.

You could also refer below article:
[“A network-related or instance-specific error occurred”](https://www.lansweeper.com/knowledgebase/a-network-related-or-instance-specific-error-occurred/)

Regards,
Jalpa.

Comment: I am trying to figure out why my app is calling aspnetdb. I want to remove any references that use it.